# Firestore takes a long time to save data upon signing up and nothing happens after that

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So I'm trying to save the user's information when they create an account into Firestore and this is my `AuthContext.js`

```
function signUp(user){
    return auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email,user.password)
    .then(async res => {           
        await updateTeacherDatabase(res.user.uid, user)
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
}
```

the `auth` variable is from firebase.js:

```
const app = firebase.initializeApp({...})

export const auth = app.auth(); //authentication
```

this is the updateTeacherDatabase function:

```
function updateTeacherDatabase(userID, user){
    return db.collection('teacher-info').doc(userID).set({
        email: user.email,
        firstName: user.firstName,
        lastName: user.lastName,
        role: 'teacher'
    }).catch(error => console.log(error))
}
```

When the user creates and account and they submits the form, it should redirect them to the home page if there's no error. However, mine just stays on the sign up page for a really long time. My submit button is grey out to indicate that the form is sending data to the back end.

I checked my firestore Auth, the user is created but not the document in `teacher-info` collection. When I commented out the `.then` part, everything works as usual, or when I deleted the `async await`, it worked but the database is not updated. My `console.log` is clear, there's no error so I really don't know how to fix this issue?

Comment: The first thing I notice is that updateTeacherDatabase is not an async function

Comment: I tried it but same thing happened. Auth updated but not the database and got the net::ERR_FAILED 200